# Why new FontFamily("Invalid font") doesn't throw an Exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, font-family

Why the following code does not throw an exception?

```
FontFamily font = new FontFamily("bla bla bla");
```

I need to know if a specific `font` (as combination of FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, ...) exists in my current OS. How have I to do?

Comment: Should throw an exception according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2ext31w1.aspx

Comment: @Artur Udod: That's `System.Drawing.FontFamily`, which isn't part of WPF.

Comment: @BoltClock, didn't notice the wpf tag =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design.  Programs frequently ask for fonts that are not present on the machine, especially in a country far flung from the programmer's domicile.  The font mapper produces an alternative.  Font substitution is in general very common.  You are looking at Arial right now if you are on a Windows machine.  But I can paste 你好世界 into this post and you'll see it render accurately, even though Arial doesn't have glyphs for Chinese characters.

So hint number one is to not actually worry about what fonts are available.  The Windows api has EnumFontFamiliesEx() to enumerate available font families.  But that's not exposed in WPF, some friction with OpenType there, a font standard that's rather poorly integrated with Windows.  Another shadow cast when Adobe gets involved with anything Microsoft does, it seems.

Some confusion in the comments about Winforms' FontFamily class.  Which is actually usable in this case, its GetFamilies() method returns an array of available families.  But only TrueType, not OpenType fonts.

Comment: I have this application that crashes, without throwing any exception, only if it runs on some machine and only if I set certain type of font (for example italic Nina). But it has a normal behavior when I run it on other machine or if i set a different font (normal Nina). How can you explain this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class `System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection.aspx

WPF have a framework specific method `Fonts.SystemFontFamilies`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fonts.systemfontfamilies.aspx

Comment: But how can I know if, for example, the Nina (italic and bold) font exists using FontFamilies?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of why it isn't throwing an exception, according to [FontFamily Constructor on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ext31w1%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the exception wasn't added until framework version 3.5.

I suspect that you are targeting version 3.0 or below.

Cheers!

Comment: That's `System.Drawing.FontFamily`. `System.Windows.Media.FontFamily`'s constructor never throws exceptions unless the argument is null.

Comment: No, The constructor throws an ArgumentNullException if the argument is null, but in my case it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the available fonts on the System using the Fonts.SystemFontFamilies collection - use some Linq to match on whatever conditions you need;

```
// true
bool exists = (from f in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies where f.Source.Equals("Arial") select f).Any();

// false
exists = (from f in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies where f.Source.Equals("blahblah") select f).Any();
```

Comment: Having said this - Hans Passant's answer is probably more appropriate.